# Error Occurred During Flow: Apex CPU Time imit exceeded

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

I am receiving this 'Apex CPU time limit exceeded' error on my flow

Flow:

[image]

Flow start object record filtering
[image]

Get Records

I am collecting the Product2 records with some conditions and iterations it over loop elemnt and sending email notifications to useers

[image]

Loop element

[image]

Email alert

[image]

How can I avoid this limit exception error?

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's important to realize that the cause of a limits exception can be different from where the exception ends up being thrown. You need to obtain a debug log and pore over it to determine where the problem actually lies (looking at the difference in CPU time when limits are occasionally reported is a good starting point). Another thing you need to know is _how many records (and of which types) are you working on?_

Comment: yes i debuged the flow, for each elemt in the loop, it is sending an email alert, i think due to lot of records, cpu limit exceeded

Comment: You shouldn't be sending email in a loop, though. That's definitely a problem.

Comment: Thanks..can you please tell me how i can modify this flow? How i can send emails outside loop for each record

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox..it worked